# How to handle multiple protobuff messages in same RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

My problem is I'm using single queue (as an entry-point to my service) and use Go consumer to handle incoming messages.

My consumer

```
    message := pb.GetRequest{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(msg.Body, message)
```

My problems is my consumer is hard wired  to handle GetRequests only. If I need to handle other type of message ie. AddRequest either

1. I need to define a new queue for each message or
2. I need to see if the first unmartial (GetRequest), and continue to test if it can be unmartialed to (AddRequest)

Is there any other good way of doing this (provided #1 is not a good option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `switch` on the RabbitMQ routing key.

The `Channel.Consume` method returns a Go channel of type `<-chan amqp.Delivery`, where [`amqp.Delivery`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery) contains the field `RoutingKey`.

The routing key is the identifier used to match published messages to consumer subscriptions. You should make sure that your publishers maintain a one-to-one association between routing keys and message types.

The publisher code will look like this:

```
msg := &pb.AddRequest{} // some protobuf generated type
body, _ := proto.Marshal(msg)
err := ch.Publish(
        "my-exchange", // exchange name
        "foo.bar.add", // routing key
        true,          // option: mandatory
        true,          // option: immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "application/x-protobuf",
            Body:        body,
        },
    )
```

In the example above, you must ensure that **all and only** messages of type `*pb.AddRequest` are published with the routing key `foo.bar.add`, i.e. that your message types are deterministic.

If you can do that, then your consumer code can switch on the routing key and unmarshal the MQ payload into a variable of the correct type:

```
func formatEvent(payload amqp.Delivery) (proto.Message, error) {

    var event proto.Message

    // switch on the routing key
    switch payload.RoutingKey {
    case "foo.bar.add":
        event = &pb.AddRequest{}
    case "foo.bar.get":
        event = &pb.GetRequest{}
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown routingKey: %s", key)
    }

    // unmarshal the body into the event variable
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(payload.Body, event); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return event, nil
}
```

And then you can [type-switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) on the `proto.Message` instance to handle each concrete message type. (Of course you can also directly handle the concrete message in the routing key switch; that will depend on how you want to organize your code).

Answer (score -1):

If your consumer is only able to handle some of the messages routed to the queue he consumes from and the consumer can't be extended to handle different types of messages, you will have to prevent the messages from reaching the queue in the first place. This is a job for the RabbitMQ server and possible the producer.

You don't provide enough information that allows us to suggest how to configure the RabbitMQ exchanges, queues and bindings. Maybe the messages carry some header information that allows the RabbitMQ server to distinguish different types of messages. If there is no such information, maybe the message producers can be extended to add such header information.

Simply rejecting (NACK) a message which your consumer can't handle is a bad idea. This will just place the message back into the same queue. If there is no other consumer that can handle it, this message will never be consumed successfully (ACK).